# Office 2013 uninstall hanging

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office-2013

I tried Office 2013, but now wish to uninstall it. I tried to uninstall it but it always hangs at step  2 out of 4. It uses no CPU and no disk activity. So basically it's just idle.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you check this official article already? [How to uninstall Office 2013 or Office 365](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501/en-us)

Comment: I'll check it out later (i can't download it now because I'm behind a proxy blocking it)

Comment: The article provides manual instructions too, if you're comfortable enough following them.

Comment: I'm not "that" motivated today. I'll look into it later. Thanks anyway

Comment: @and31415 this solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

Microsoft provides an automated removal tool which should uninstall Office 2013 and remove any leftovers.

### Automatic fix-it solution

1. Download and run this Microsoft Fix it package: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9815935
2. Restart Windows when you're done.

### Manual steps

In case you're unable to completely uninstall Office with the above method, try the following manual uninstall steps.

> #### Step 1: Remove any remaining Windows Installer packages for the Office 2013 system
>
> 1. Use one of the following methods to open the Run dialog box.
>
>    **For Windows 7**
>
>    a. Click **Start**. Click **All Programs**, and then open the **Accessories** folder.
>
>    b. Click **Run**.
>
>    **For Windows 8 or Windows 8.1**
>
>    a. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap **Search**. If you are using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click **Search**.
>
>    b. In the **Search** box, type `Run`. In the search results, click **Run** to open it.
> 2. Type `installer`, and then click **OK**.
>
>    **Note** This opens the `%windir%\Installer` folder.
> 3. On the **View** menu, click **Choose Details**.
> 4. Click to select the **Subject** check box, type `340` in the **Width of selected column (in pixels)** box, and then click **OK**.
>
>    **Note** It may take several minutes for the subjects to appear next to each `.msi` file.
> 5. On the **View** menu, point to **Sort By**, and then click **Subject**.
> 6. If a **User Account Control** dialog box appears, click **Allow** to continue.
> 7. Locate each `.msi` file where the subject is "Microsoft Office  2013," right-click the `.msi` file, and then click **Uninstall**.
>
>    **Note** The  placeholder represents the name of the Office 2013 product.
>
> #### Step 2: Stop the Office Source Engine service
>
> 1. Open the **Run** dialog box.
> 2. Type `services.msc`, and then click **OK**.
> 3. In the **Services** window, determine whether the **Office Source Engine** service is running. (If it is, "Started" will appear in the **Status** column.) If this service is running, right-click **Office Source Engine**, and then click **Stop**.
> 4. Close the **Services** window.
>
> #### Step 3: Delete any remaining Office 2013 installation folders
>
> 1. Open the **Run** dialog box.
> 2. Type `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared`, and then click **OK**.
>
>    **Note** On a computer that's running a 64-bit version of Windows, type `%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared`, and then click **OK**.
> 3. If the following folders are present, delete them:
>
>    - `Office15`
>    - `Source Engine`
> 4. Open the **Run** dialog box.
> 5. Type `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office`, and then click **OK**.
>
>    **Note** On a computer that's running a 64-bit version of Windows, type `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office`, and then click **OK**.
> 6. Delete the `Office15` folder.
> 7. On the root folder of each hard disk, locate and then open the `MSOCache` folder. If you don't see this folder, follow these steps:
>
>    a. Open Windows Explorer, and then on the **Tools** menu, click **Folder Options**.
>
>    b. Click the **View** tab.
>
>    c. In the **Advanced settings** pane, under **Hidden files and folders**, click **Show hidden files and folders**.
>
>    d. Clear the **Hide protected operating system files** check box, and then click **OK**.
>
>    - Open the `All Users` folder in the `MSOCache` folder, and then delete every folder that contains `0FF1CE}-` text in the folder name.
>
>      **Note** This text contains a 0 (zero) and a 1 for the letters "O" and "I."
>        **Example** `{90150000-001B-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C`
>
> #### Step 4: Delete any remaining Office 2013 installation files
>
> 1. Open the **Run** dialog box.
> 2. Type `%appdata%\microsoft\templates`, and then click **OK**.
> 3. Delete the following files:
>
>    - `Normal.dotm`
>    - `Welcome to Word.dotx`
> 4. Open the **Run** dialog box.
> 5. Type `%appdata%\microsoft\document building blocks`, and then click **OK**.
> 6. Open the subfolder under the `Document Building Blocks` folder.
>
>    **Note** The subfolder title will be a four-digit number that represents the language of the Microsoft Office suite.
> 7. Delete the `building blocks.dotx` file.
> 8. Exit all programs before you follow the rest of the steps.
>
> #### Step 5: Delete the registry subkeys for the Office 2013 system
>
> **Warning** Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method. These problems might require that you reinstall the operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can be solved. Modify the registry at your own risk.
>
> **Important** This article contains information about how to modify the registry. Make sure that you back up the registry before you modify it. Make sure that you know how to restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up, restore, and modify the registry, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>   [322756](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756/en-us) How to back up and restore the registry in Windows
>
> Locate and then delete the Office 2013 registry subkeys if they are present. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the **Run** dialog box.
> 2. Type `regedit`, and then click **OK**.
> 3. Click the following registry subkey:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0
>    ```
> 4. On the **File** menu, click **Export**, type `DeletedKey01`, and then click **Save**.
> 5. On the **Edit** menu, click **Delete**, and then click **Yes** to confirm.
> 6. Repeat these steps (1 through 7) for each registry subkey in the following list. Change the name of the exported key by one for each subkey.
>
>    **Example:** Type `DeletedKey02` for the second key, type `DeletedKey03` for the third key, and so on.
>
>    **Note** In the following registry keys, the asterisk character (*) represents one or more characters in the subkey name.
>
> **32-bit versions of Windows**
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Delivery\SourceEngine\Downloads\*0FF1CE}-*
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*0FF1CE*
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Upgrade Codes\*F01FEC
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\*F01FEC
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ose
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Features\*F01FEC
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\*F01FEC
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\*F01FEC
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Win32Assemblies\*Office15*
> ```
>
> **64-bit versions of Windows**
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Delivery\SourceEngine\Downloads\*0FF1CE}-*
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*0FF1CE*
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ose
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Features\*F01FEC
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\*F01FEC
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\*F01FEC
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Win32Asemblies\*Office15*
> ```
>
> Also delete the following registry subkeys:
>
> 1. Locate one of the following subkeys, depending on the version of Windows that you're running:
>
>    - 32-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
>    - 64-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`\Uninstall
> 2. On the **File** menu, click **Export**, type `UninstallKey01`, and then click **Save**.
> 3. Under the `Uninstall` subkey that you located in step 1, click each subkey, and then determine whether the subkey has the following value assigned to it:
>
>    - Name: `UninstallString`
>    - Data: `file_name path\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe path`
>
>      **Note** In this example, `file_name` is a placeholder for the name of an installation program, and `path` is a placeholder for the file path.
> 4. If the subkey contains the name and the data that are described in step 3, click **Delete** on the **Edit** menu. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until you locate and then delete every subkey that matches the name and the data that are described in step 3.
> 6. Close Registry Editor.
>
> <sub>Source: [How to uninstall Office 2013 or Office 365](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501/en-us)</sub>

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2013-Office-2016-or-Office-365-from-a-Windows-computer-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8