# Uninstalled microsoft office professional 2013 but why is it still listed in my control panel?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, uninstall, microsoft-office-2013

I followed the instructions using microsoft fix it 2010 and it said that it was successfully uninstalled and I even followed the instructions from step 2 as well. But when I restarted my laptop for step 2 and checked my control panel to see if microsoft office professional 2013 was removed from the list, it was STILL there. Whenever I would uninstall for this, a setup error would pop up saying "this product has been corrupted. run setup again from the CD, DVD, or other original installation source". The problem is that I no longer have the original source. :(

Any answers as to why its still there? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Its not there.  You forced the uninstallation.  Just remove the entry by attempting to uninstall it or using a program like CCleaner.  But why are you using a tool for Office 2010 to remove Office 2013?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate question: [Office 2013 uninstall hanging](http://superuser.com/questions/742839/office-2013-uninstall-hanging)

Answer (score 0):

We've had this before and the Microsoft FixIt Portable resolved it. Just pick the "having problem installing or uninstalling" and it let's you pick the application to completely remove. It does a pretty good job too!