# Completely remove everything of Microsoft Office to reinstall it from crash

Tags: microsoft-office, uninstall

I want to have complete Microsoft Office suite be removed as nothing related to Office exists on my computer.

I tried to uninstall from Control Panel but it seems the `underground` data still remained somewhere after I reinstall the software. E.g. the previous Office license, my Outlook mail box.

Currently I have Office 2013 and Visio 2010 on my machine.

How can I completely remove Office?

Comment: I'd start with ccleaner, and see if that can find any per user configuration sources and registery keys.

Comment: @and31415 Indeed the similar solution is here http://superuser.com/a/744977/34893 Please make your own separate answer to get accepted

Comment: @FrankThomas You are suggesting CCleaner which has virus detected by virustotal.com as scanned here https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/a9976d7f84e362735fb843b8620faff26d743d1216c0eb05b8619250726f996b/analysis/1406354528/

Comment: @NamGVU If the solution provided there works for you, it's better to just mark this question as duplicate rather then posting the same answer twice. As for CCleaner, there's no "virus" as long as you download it from the Piriform website. NOD32 detects it as `Win32/Bundled.Toolbar.Google.D`, which is a warning about a potentially unwanted application. Either way, since it's not a program specifically designed to remove Office leftovers, it would likely miss something. It's better to either use the official cleanup utility or follow the manual steps provided (if you feel confident enough).

Comment: @and31415 The two questions are different but have the same answer. That's not duplicated question. Thanks anyway!