# Office 2016/Office 365 uninstall hanging

Tags: microsoft-office, uninstall, office365, microsoft-office-2016

Similar to the circumstances in [Office 2013 uninstall hanging](https://superuser.com/questions/742839/office-2013-uninstall-hanging), I needed to uninstall a local copy of Office 2016 that I got through my Office 365 account. Unfortunately, the uninstall process is hanging - it stays at "step 1 of 4" for 30 minutes on a pretty fast machine with no CPU or network usage. How can I actually uninstall it?

Comment: What's the "step 1 of 4"? The uninstall process you posted is for manually removing an MSI installation of Office. And your Office 2016 installation is click-to-run version that you installed with Office 365 account. It is not suitable for your scenario. Try to use easy fix tool as suggestion below.

Comment: @WinniL The click-to-run uninstaller was hanging with the text "step 1 of 4", and using the tool provided by Microsoft uninstalled it fine. I'm not sure how it's not suitable if it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides a few options in [their thorough and easy-to-follow Office uninstall article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8):

1. Uninstall normally (via Control Panel)
2. Uninstall using their [easy fix tool](https://aka.ms/diag_officeuninstall)
3. Uninstall manually

For me, the easy fix tool worked.

Answer (score -1):

## **Manually remove an click-to-run version of Office 2016**:

**Step 1: Remove the Windows Installer packages**

1. Find the Office 16 installation folder, typically located in C:\Program Files.
2. Right-click the Microsoft Office 16 folder and select Delete.

**Step 2: Remove the Office scheduled tasks**

1. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
2. At the command prompt, type the following commands and press Enter after each one:

schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office Automatic Updates"

schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office Subscription Maintenance"

schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office ClickToRun Service Monitor"

schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\OfficeTelemetryAgentLogOn2016"

schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\OfficeTelemetryAgentFallBack2016"

**Step 3: Use Task Manager to end the Click-to-Run tasks**

1. Open Task Manager.

**Windows 10**: Right-click Start, and click Task Manager. (The keyboard shortcut Windows logo key + X also works to open the access menu.)

**Windows 8 or 8.1**: Point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search. Type Task Manager in the search box, and then click Task Manager in the results.

**Windows 7**: Right-click an empty area of the taskbar, and then click Start Task Manager.

2. Click the **Process** tab.
3. If the following processes are running, right-click each one, and then click End task in Windows 10, End Task in Windows 8 or 8.1, or End Process in Windows 7 after you select each process.

OfficeClickToRun.exe

OfficeC2RClient.exe

AppVShNotify.exe

setup*.exe

**Step 4: Delete the Office service**

Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator, type the following command, and then press Enter:

sc delete ClickToRunSvc

**Step 5: Delete the Office files**

1. Press Windows logo key + R to open the Run dialog box.
2. In the Open box, type %ProgramFiles%, and then click OK.
3. Delete the "Microsoft Office 16" folder.
4. Delete the “Microsoft Office” folder.
5. Open the Run dialog box, type %ProgramFiles(x86)%, and then click OK.
6. Delete the “Microsoft Office” folder.
7. Open the Run dialog box, type %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared and then click OK.
8. Delete the “ClickToRun” folder.
9. Open the Run dialog box, type %ProgramData%\Microsoft, and then click OK.
10. Delete the ClickToRun folder. If the folder does not exist, go to the next step.
11. Open the Run dialog box, type %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Office, and then click OK.
12. Delete the ClickToRunPackagerLocker file.

Note: If you can't delete a folder or a file that's open or that's being used by another program, restart the computer, and then try again. If you still can't remove the folder, go to the next step.

**Step 6: Delete the Office registry subkeys**

Important: Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems may occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you start, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.

1. Open Registry Editor.

**Windows 10**: Right-click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

**Windows 8 or 8.1**: Right-click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

**Windows 7**: Click Start, type Run in the Start Search box, and then click Run in the results.

2. Delete the following registry subkeys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppVISV

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Office  - en-us

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office

Then **Delete** the Office key.

Note: In the subkey in the third bullet item, "Microsoft Office - en-us" represents the actual program name. This name depends on the Office 2016 edition and language version that you installed.

**Step 7: Delete the Start menu shortcuts**

1. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
2. Type %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs, and then press Enter.
3. Delete the “Microsoft Office 2016 Tools” folder.
4. Delete each of the “ 2016” shortcuts for each of the Office 2016 applications. For example, “Word 2016”, “Excel 2016”, “PowerPoint 2016”.

**Step 8: Uninstall the Office 16 Click-To-Run Licensing Component, Extensibility Component and Localization Component**

1. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
2. At the command prompt, type the command that is appropriate for your operating system, and then press Enter:

If you're running an x86 version of Office 2016 on an x64 operating system, run the following commands:

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}**

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}**

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008C-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}**

If you're running an x86 version of Office 2016 on an x86 operating system, run the following command:

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-007E-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}**

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}**

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008C-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}**

If you're running an x64 version of Office 2016 on an x64 operating system, run the following command:

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-007E-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}**

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008C-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}**

**MsiExec.exe /X{90160000-008C-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}**

Comment: This answer just copies the contents of https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manually-uninstall-office-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b without linking to the source and ignores that they have an [easy fix tool](https://aka.ms/diag_officeuninstall) that fixes the issue as well (at least in some cases).